# Unable to find all contours using findcontours and opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to find contours using opencv findcontours, but some contours are missing from quite a simple image. The image is created in the create_mat() function and in rbt the findcontours is used. I have tried changing the mode in findcontours using: CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_RETR_LIST... I have tried all of them, and changing the method: CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE ....

The opencv version is 3.3

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#define SIZE_XX 750
#define SIZE_YY 3000
int im_mat[SIZE_XX][SIZE_YY];
cv::Mat create_mat(){
    for(int i=0;i <SIZE_XX;i++){
        int index=0;
        for(int j=0;j<SIZE_YY;j++){
            im_mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    Mat circle1 = cv::Mat(SIZE_XX,SIZE_YY,CV_8UC1,im_mat);
    int thickness = -1;
    int lineType = 8;
    circle( circle1,Point(10,60),25,Scalar(255),thickness,lineType );
    circle( circle1,Point(35,10),25,Scalar(255),thickness,lineType );
    rectangle( circle1,Point( 200,400),Point( 500, 600),Scalar( 255 ),-1,8 );
    circle( circle1,Point(350,35),25,Scalar(255),thickness,lineType );
    rectangle( circle1,Point( 1500,500),Point( 2098, 600),Scalar( 255 ),-1,8 );
    circle( circle1,Point(35,160),25,Scalar(255),thickness,lineType );
    circle( circle1,Point(2000,160),25,Scalar(255),thickness,lineType );
    rectangle( circle1,Point( 1000,0),Point( 1100, 200),Scalar( 255 ),-1,8 );
    rectangle( circle1,Point( 1800,25),Point( 1650, 200),Scalar( 255 ),-1,8 );
    rectangle( circle1,Point( 200,200),Point( 300, 300),Scalar( 255 ),-1,8 );
    rectangle( circle1,Point( 625,625),Point( 825, 750),Scalar( 255 ),-1,8 );
    rectangle( circle1,Point( 1300,35),Point( 1450, 400),Scalar( 255 ),-1,8 );
    return circle1;
}
void rbt(){
    Mat src= create_mat();
    Mat oi,oi2,oi3,oi4;
    src.copyTo(oi);
    cv::resize(oi, oi, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
    cv::imshow("test1",oi);
    cv::waitKey(1000);
    Mat gray;
    threshold(src, gray,0, 255,THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::resize(gray, oi2, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
    imshow("grays",oi2);
    Rect bounding_rect;
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    Mat cpy;
    gray.copyTo(cpy);

    findContours( cpy, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE  );

    RNG rg(12345);
    Mat destination(gray.rows, gray.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar( rg.uniform(75, 175), rg.uniform(75,175), rg.uniform(75,175) );
        drawContours( destination, contours, i, color, -1,8,hierarchy );
        cv::resize(destination, oi3, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
        cv::imshow("drawing",oi3);
        cv::waitKey(1000);
    }
    waitKey(0);                                         
}
```

I have also tried finding the edges first using canny, but the results were even worse.

The image is a black background with white objects to find the contours.

My contour image is missing: Circles at (35,10) and (350,35) plus rectangle at (1000,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs fine for me!

[image]

I would suggest either providing more details about what is not working **with pictures of your output**, and checking you are linking to all the libraries etc.

All i did was copy and paste your code into my Visual Studio OpenCV 3.3.0 Test environment.

Comment: Well, for me the exact code misses two circles and one rectangle. Circles at (35,10) and (350,35) plus rectangle at (1000,0). It is driving me a bit crazy. Are you using opencv 3.3?

Comment: I am using OpenCV 3.3.0 however it shouldn't make any difference if you are using either 3.X or 2.X I don't think find contours has changed much.

Comment: I am using 3.3.0, no idea why this doesn't work. Thanks for letting me know yours works (finds all contours), I will try this with a different machine and version of opencv.

Comment: linking debug libraries in release build or vice-versa?

Comment: I remade opencv 3.3.0 and now it finds all the contours normally, still have no idea why it didn't work before. Both times I was using opencv_world330.lib and opencv_world330.dll, and not the debug libraries. Thanks.